# Check if user exist with mysqli doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='Steve Job'");
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->num_rows){
    echo "1";
}
```

it return blank in my ajax callback. I've debugging for hours.

Comment: And you are sure you have a record where `name = 'Steve Job'`

Comment: you missed `$stmt->store_result();` after the `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @ponciste already mentioned in my answer friend :)

Comment: Probably because his name is Steve _Jobs_ :-) In any case, you could probably get away with `select 1` or `select count(*)` so s to avoid all of Steve's information having to come across the wire. There are precious few situations where `select *` makes sense, detecting the existence of a row is certainly not one of them.

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes, 20 seconds earlier :-)

Comment: Haha sorry @ponciste didn't realise it was that close

Comment: @AndyHolmes no problem. Btw i marked your answer as useful

Comment: @paxdiablo so instead of select all what you suggest? select name?

Comment: user3318525, I suggest `count(*)` - it should simply give you a single row holding a single value, no need to transfer a lot of stuff over the wire. This may become important when your DB server is a thousand kilometers away and there are ten million rows :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a row exists in MySQL? (i.e. check if an email exists in MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/how-to-check-if-a-row-exists-in-mysql-i-e-check-if-an-email-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='Steve Job'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0){
    echo "1";
}
```

You need to use `store_result` before working with `num_rows`